# trigger resize event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webbrowser-control

Hello I'm looking for a simple way to resize the content of my body , something equivalent to what happens when the user hits Ctrl+ or Ctrl- , but I want to trigger it automatically based on the size of the browser size:

for example :

```
if($(window).width() > 1200){

//do resize

}
```

can somebody help?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You want to resize the window, or detect when the window is resized?

Comment: Are you trying to make the elements on the page fit a certain size on the screen? Like small or large enough to fill the windows without having scroll bars?

Comment: @David thanks, I want to resize the window, I don't really care about detection

Comment: @Jared more or less yes, that's what I want to do ,but I wouldn't like to have a liquid effect

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't something like this be simple enough with the proper CSS styling? I'm thinking assigning rules that rely on percentage values that resize along with the containing element (like a browser viewport).

Granted, that may not work with every CSS element (I'm thinking mmmmm maybe `font-size`?). I'd suggest going for a CSS approach if what you want to resize can be done in CSS anyway.

**UPDATE**

Based on what you said on the comments, what you want to do sounds a tad bit complex, but I'd probably tackle it by doing the following:

*Declare a viewport benchmark*

```
// working on just width
var basewidth = 960;
```

*Declare base values for your CSS styles*

```
var basecss = {
    fontsize: 12,
    borderwidth: 2
}
```

*Then trigger some calculations on resize*

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var ratio = $(this).width() / basewidth;
    $('#baseContainer *').each(
        $(this).css({
            'font-size' : basecss.fontsize * ratio + 'pt',
            'border-width' : basecss.borderwidth * ratio + 'px'
        });
    );
});
```

or something along those lines. of course, going for the `*` selector is overkill.

Comment: that's what I was thinking also so I tried something like body{width:80%;} but it won't work as you expect it won't resize the elements it will just use a smaller amount of the screen

Answer (score 0):

jQuery trigger should do this with the resize event, no?
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look to `matchMedia()` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia

Answer (score -4):

In your browser window, there are resize handles. Just have your users grab those and resize your window when you think the size is right.

Comment: thanks but I would like that to happen automatically...otherwise I wouldn't ask at all :)

Comment: Oh, automatically! Duh. You should use JavaScript for that.

Comment: That would be why he used the 'javascript' and 'jquery' tags. :)